# Understanding scope of private method

Tags: java

A friend of mine asked this question to me. Why the following code does not give error on invoking aa.x()? 
I understand that aa is a reference to object of class B but is invoking private method of class A inside the method of class A where it is visible and hence accessible. 
 
Is my understanding correct? Or is there any other reason behind this?

```
public class A {
    public void xyz() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    private void x() {
        System.out.println("A:x");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A aa = b;
        aa.x();
        aa.xyz();
        B bb = (B) aa;
        bb.xyz();
        bb.xyz12();
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void xyz() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    public void xyz12() {
        System.out.println("B-12");
    }
}
```

Comment: So many duplicates, so little time... *Edit:* Er, well, maybe not with the subclass wrinkle.

Comment: If you want it to understand please read about access modifiers here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. private access modifier is for Class and main is in this class so there is no problem to call that method

Comment: Here one might as well write `A aa = new A()` instead of `A aa = b`. Since `A aa = b` is legal and `aa.x()` is legal inside `A#main()`, everything ok.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. If it was a public method, it would have been inherited by Class B and during runtime the class B's method would have got executed. If the method is not inherited and only present in B then compiler throws error.

Answer (score 3):

I can't immediately find a duplicate using a subclass, but fundamentally it's the same answer as the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482579/how-is-this-private-variable-accessible).

There are two things that govern access to `x`:

1. Where the code is that's doing the access. Since `x` is private to `A`, the code accessing it must be part of a method in `A`. It can't be in a subclass (`B`) or an unrelated class.
2. What kind of reference you're using. If you have an `A` reference, you can access `x` on it. If you have a `B` reference, you can't, *even though* your code is part of an `A` method. You could cast it to `A` and then access `x`, but you can't do it directly with a reference of type `B`.

Comment: It's less about where the code is located and more about the compile time type of `aa`. You wouldn't be able to do `b.x()` inside `A`. Runtime types don't matter. Scope and accessibility is all about compile time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: That's true *too*, but if you have an `A` reference `a`, you can't do `a.x()` in non-`A` code, either,

Comment: Sure, but I don't think that's what they're asking.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: *"...is invoking private method of class A inside the method of class A where it is visible and hence accessible..."* Where teh code is that's being run seems pretty applicable to me.

Comment: The issue can be simplified since having `B` here is irrelevant (as it extends `A` and thus is an `A`). It's the exact same question that you reference.

Comment: @Kenney: Which is why I linked it, in a CW answer. But they *aren't* the same question, just closely-related. So Sotirios points out, there's the question of the reference type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How did you add the answer to community wiki?

Comment: @prudhvi: You have that option when adding an answer (or editing your own answer), it's a tickbox under the text area.

Comment: Haven't delved into CW yet, but I am agreeing with you. As far as I can tell they are the same question, once you remove the irrelevant code from OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

It is only visible because the main method where it is invoked is contained in class A. Move it to class B and it will not work

Answer (score 0):

As the private methods are not inherited, a superclass reference calls its own private method.

Your `main` method is the method of `A`, therefore it can can call `x()` private method.

> private modifier—the field is accessible only within its own class.